# ASP.Net 6 Web API and MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a web app using the newly released VS 2015 using ASP.Net Web API (MVC 6 aka ASP.Net vNext).

I'm trying to use the latest MongoDB driver (Mongo.Driver 2.0.1). I have added the reference via NuGet and I see it in the project.json and the references, however, when I attempt to use it in code (same project) I have no access to it.

For instance, a using statement followed by the word Mongo yields nothing. Writing out var mongo = new Mongo provides no intellisense to add the using statement. It's as if the reference didn't exist (yet it does in the project.json and the references). Is the latest MongoDB driver not compatible with the latest version of ASP.Net?

Comment: Build MongoDB with ASP.Net MVC 6 http://www.code-sample.com/2016/07/mongodb-connection-string-mvc-6.html

Answer (score 0):

Installing the driver worked in my version of visual studio (2015 RTM). I did have to remove the dnxcore50 line in project.json to make the driver work as the current Mongo release doesn't appear to support it:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
},
```

Comment: I don't have a dnxcore50 line. I have a "dotnet" : {}. I tried replacing it with your line but I got an error. I'm using the RTM version.